# javascript wont change the thing what i change

Tags: javascript

Soo i have 2 buttons, button to open sidebar and button to submit or to change page. I made a mistake by making both button ids with the name `buton` and i change the open sidebar to `buttonMenu`

So I have an openNav function like so

.js

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("buttonMenu").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
```

button.php

```
// Button to open sidebar

<button class="btn btn-label openbtn float-left" id="buttonMenu" onclick="openNav()"><span class="fas fa-bars"></span></button>

// Button to change pages

<button class="btn btn-primary float-right" name="simpan" type="submit" style="margin-bottom:50px;" id="buton">Save</button>
```

.css

```
  /* Edited button style */
  #buton{
      background-color: #bdbdbd;
      color: white;
      border : none;
      border-style:solid;
  }

  /* Edited Button Atribut */
  #buton:hover{
      background-color: white;
      color: #bdbdbd;
      border: none;
      border-style:solid;
  }

  /* Edited Menu Button Style */
  #buttonMenu{
      background-color: #bdbdbd;
      color: white;
      border : none;
      border-style:solid;
  }

  /* Edited Menu Button Atribut */
  #buttonMenu:hover{
      background-color: white;
      color: #bdbdbd;
      border: none;
      border-style:solid;
  }
```

how i import my .js file in header

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = "<?php echo base_url();?>js/sidebar.js"></script>
```

the other one is `closeNav()` where it makes the button visible

But after I changed the id from the functions to `buttonMenu`, the code doesn't work, but it works with the old id `"buton"`. Then I put those code on a seperate .js file and not at `<script>`, but if i put those code inside `<script>` it works. What is happening here?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Also see https://shouldiblamecaching.com/ and check in your browser's debugger that the .js file your browser sees really contains the code you think it does.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and be sure to show what you have tried and researched. Why are you trying to change the id? You need to include an example of the HTML as well.

Comment: okay i already add some of my code, hope its helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You use inline `onclick` or `eventlistener`?

Maybe you forgot to declare something for new id

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementById("buttonMenu").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  document.getElementById("buttonMenu").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" style="overflow-x:hidden;width:0px;background-color:red;position:absolute">xxx</div>
<div id="main" style="overflow-x:hidden;background-color:yellow;">main</div>

<button id="buttonMenu" onclick="openNav()">openNav</button>
<button id="buton" onclick="closeNav()">closeNav</button>
```

Comment: yeah i have onclick that i already change the id but it still didn't work, i think i should just use `<script>` ii somehow think that the problem is from how i import the .js file

Comment: How PHP echo out the js source?